# Checking for a number if first 4 digits forward equals last 4 digits backwards

Tags: python, string

If the last 4 elements stepping forward are equal to the last 4 elements stepping backwards, print the number. I have input a number where the last 4 elements are clearly palindromic. Why does this not print the number?

```
def checkNum(i):
    num = str(i)
    if num[len(num)-5:len(num)-1:1] == num[len(num)-5:len(num)-1:-1]:
        print(num)
checkNum(777777)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing your two values that you are comparing?

Comment: Yes everything works except for the -1 step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the slices wrong. The left part of the string should be sliced like that: `num[:4]` and the right part should be sliced like that: `num[:-5:-1]`
**Edit for the comment**:
You can always print the slices you're attempting to use in the function. To get the problem, use something more visualising than 777777. For example: 123456789. Then, if you print your slices in the function, you will see the strings that you are comparing:

```
def checkNum(i):
    num = str(i)
    print(num[-4:])
    print(num[-4::-1])
    print(num[-5:-1])
checkNum(123456789)
```

The output you'll get is:

```
6789
654321
9876
```

This shows the way slices work. When you're using negative indexes, you're starting from the end with a positive step, so `num[-4:]` returns the last 4 characters in the original order. The negative step returns the first characters reversed. Consider some manual testing, it really saves a lot of time.

Comment: Well I get what you mean, but this is actually wrong. Can you tell my why this doesn't work? num[-4:] == num[-4::-1]:

Comment: Ok so for future readers, Leva7's function as edited returns the number that is wholly palindromic, from beginning to end.

Comment: @PencilCrate check out what I've wrote

Comment: This is a great description of how negative indexes work. Great examples.

Comment: How do you get the last 4 in reverse

Comment: @PencilCrate Since I'm using a negative step, it starts at the end of a string, returning `num[-1]`, then `num[-2]` and so on until `[-4]` (the last index is excluded in Python slices)

Answer (score 1):

You are going backwards from `len(num)-1` to `len(num)-5` in the latter part of the equality!

Here's the correct version:

```
def checkNum(i):
num = str(i)
if num[len(num)-5:len(num)-1:1] == num[len(num)-1:len(num)-5:-1]:
    print(num)
checkNum(777777)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> num = str(777777)
>>> print num[len(num)-5:len(num)-1:1]
7777
>>> print num[len(num)-5:len(num)-1:-1]
***None***
```

To access the last four from the last position, you need

```
>>> print num[len(num)-1:len(num)-5:-1]
7777

def checkNum(i):
    num = str(i)
    if num[len(num)-5:len(num)-1:1] == num[len(num)-1:len(num)-5:-1]:
        print(num)

>>> checkNum(777777)
777777
```

Comment: While this does work, it is nowhere as efficient as it could be. Performance tests using the `timeit` module show that your way of slicing works twice as long because of accessing the string length

Answer (score 1):

You could take the first 4 characters forward (`[:4]`), reverse the string (`[::-1]`) and take the first 4 characters again (which are now the last 4 characters reversed):

```
def checkNum(i):
    num = str(i)
    if num[:4] == num[::-1][:4]:
        print(num)
```

---

```
>>> checkNum("11118354367451111")
11118354367451111
>>> checkNum("1111835436745111")
>>> 
>>> checkNum("otto")
otto
>>>
```